# The length of the array is wrong

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple question (Not for me anyway:)):

I have the following 3 variables and I want to put them in a array and then getting the length of this array:

```
$rank1 = "1"; 
$rank2 = "2";
$rank3 = "3";
```

I am using this code (I have to use for!!!):

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
$array_rank .= "\"\$rank".$x."\", " ;
}
$array_rank2 = array($array_rank);
$array_rank_length = count($array_rank2);
```

The length of the array should be 3, I am getting 1.

Any help whould be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you think it should be `3`? You are creating a string, then adding it to an array. When you put one thing in an array it will only ever contain one thing.

Comment: 1) You concatenate a string to an undefined variable 2) Enable error reporting to get useful error messages 3) What you want to do is use variable variables to access your variables, e.g. `${"rank" . $x}` 4) you create an array with 1 element. You just want to add them with `[]`, e.g. `$array[] = "new element";`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding a string to an array with the text '$rank1,$rank2,$rank3'. [insert image "that's not how any of this works"]

I believe what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
$rank1 = "1"; 
$rank2 = "2";
$rank3 = "3";

$array_rank = array();

for($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $array_rank[$x] = ${'rank' . $x};
}

$array_rank_length = count($array_rank); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

First correct '$rank1,$rank2,$rank3,' this (Because you are getting string)..
Then this code will help you..

```
<?php

$rank1 = "1"; 
$rank2 = "2";
$rank3 = "3";
$array_rank = '';
for($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
$array_rank.= "\"\$rank".$x."\", " ;
}
$array_rank2 = explode(',',$array_rank);
$array_rank_length = count($array_rank2)-1;

print_r($array_rank2);
print_r($array_rank_length);

?>
```